# Convert SimpleXML to DOMDocument, not DOMElement

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I need to convert a `SimpleXML` object to a `DOMDocument`, to use it with `DOMXPath`. I need DOMXPath so that I can use its `registerPHPFunctions` method. Can this be done?

With `dom_import_simplexml` I get a `DOMElement`, not `DOMDocument`.

Comment: sounds like you are no longer doing *simple* xml operations, so you might want to consider switching to DOM completely.

Comment: I am, just trying to convince myself it's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can fetch the document from [$anyDOMNode->ownerDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.ownerdocument)

Comment: Thank you! I searched for this, but didn't find it. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Can I convert an element and start using it as domdocument? How does it works?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($sxml->asXML());
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a note: The `loadXML()` method returns a boolean, and loads the XML to `$dom`. With this solution I will loose the connection to the original simple xml object, right? So say I remove the DOMElements later, this will not affect the simple xml.

Comment: code corrected. you still have access to $sxml represented here as your simplexml object. $dom and $sxml are independent of each other. whatever change you make in $dom will not affect $sxml. if you want the reverse of the above code:

`$sxml=simplexml_load_string($dom->saveXML());`

Comment: Actually, when I'm converting with `dom_import_simplexml`, it preserves the connection to simple xml. If I remove a dom node, this change ripples back to simple xml.

Comment: dom_import_simplexml does exhibit that kind of behavior. notice that the code i showed you passes strings between $dom and $sxml, so the xml trees are sesparated.